# Should users share OSX crash logs?

Tags: logging, macos

OSX stores app crash logs into ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticLogs/appname_date.crash and optionally submits these anonymously back to Apple.

These contain a fair amount of debug info for the developer, and may be useful to share with devs so they can see the cause of an error.

Should users be wary of posting these in public?

- [HT4774 - Apple Diagnostic & Usage data](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4774)
- [Example crash log posted to Cyberduck Trac](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/ticket/7079)

Comment: I see I've revealed a willingness to run java apps, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A developer crash log *may* contain personal information (e.g. names of open files or things like that). This depends on the application and on the care the developer put in the process. Generally speaking, if the application contains any personal information at all, then it is hard to guarantee that the information will not make it to a crash log, since crash logs, by definition, occur unexpectedly (if a crash is expected, it is a *feature*, not a bug).

You can try to reproduce the crash with the same application from a dummy account which, by definition, contains nothing about you. This guarantees a "clean crash log".